# Magnetic sunspot propulsion

Tags: magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, sun, propulsion, solar-wind

Could a solar sail use the sun, its sunspots, or solar flares, in close proximity, use opposing magnetic fields, to add significant acceleration?
[image]

[image]
https://www.mae.ucla.edu/nasa-selects-artur-davoyans-solar-sail-concept/

Comment: Can you quantify or further describe "significant" acceleration?

Comment: @Jonas double or more I guess.

Comment: @Justintimeforfun double or more of what, a numerical example is a lot better than a vague quantifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could a solar sail use the sun, its sunspots, or solar flares, in close proximity, use opposing magnetic fields, to add significant acceleration?

Solar sails rely on solar radiation pressure.  The ram pressure from the [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind) itself is comparably small (i.e., only a few nPa near Earth).  [Solar flares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare) and the associated energetic particles (i.e., [solar energetic particles (SEPs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_energetic_particles)) are more likely to damage the internal electronics of the spacecraft than to help accelerate it.

The magnetic field near the sun is indeed larger than it is in the solar wind near Earth, however, it is still very small (~0.1 T in the strongest active regions low in the [photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere)).  Spacecraft often have masses in excess of 1000 kg and you do not want them accumulating significant charge, so the net acceleration due to magnetic fields should be tiny.  If the spacecraft accumulates a lot of charge in order to try and increase the effect of the [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force), then the spacecraft will suffer damage from ablation caused by arcing due to electrostatic discharges.